# Is there a reason why react-dom would load both development and production versions within the same app?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-dom

While optimizing a small app, I noticed this oddity from the visualizer :

```
$ meteor --extra-packages bundle-visualizer --production
```

[image: React-DOM Development]

[image: React-DOM Production]

Why is there two (2) `React-DOM` modules loaded?

---

### ** Edit **

I'm trying to find which package depends of `react-dom-development`; why would it be included?

Comment: is this in dev or in production?

Comment: I think you should open this as an issue in their GitHub repo. Bundle vidualizer usually runs using the `--production` flag, simulating a production bundle for local analysis and this looks like something that should not be in there.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I added the command line that I used to produce this. As far as I understand, it runs in production.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I agree, but I do not know how to reproduce this; I don't know WHY this happens? I understand that creating issues without reproducible examples are hard to debug and fix. I will simply be redirected, here.

Comment: does that `..development.js` file still exist in the actual production bundle (created by `meteor build`)?

Comment: @ChristianFritz from what I can see, even the deployment tarball has both development and production scripts of each modules.

Comment: confirmed, I see it in my production builds, too.

Comment: I also encountered this issue, seems that it was reported in 2017 and has no progress: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9388